# How do I play sound thru front and rear 3.5mm headphone sockets at the same time?

Tags: sound

My setup:
Kubuntu 22.04

Speakers plugged into the back.  Good speakers but the headphone socket no longer works.  These speakers have an on/off switch and volume.

Headphone socket on the front the PC: I want to plug my wireless headphones into here without the sound cutting out to the speakers. Then I'll just switch the speakers off at the speaker.

In case you were thinking of asking:
Q: Ben, why not just unplug your wireless headphones from the front of the PC when you want to play sound via the rear socket to your speakers?

A: Because I wore out the headphone socket on the front of my previous PC doing that. I like to save my sockets.